# How to add LastWriteTime to this script?

Tags: powershell

```
$dir = "\\server\BackupBuddy" 
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Directory |
ForEach-Object{
[pscustomobject]@{
    Folder = $_.Name
    Count = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -File).Count
    }
} | Select-Object Folder,Count
```

**Would be even better if the files were filtered by at least 2 days old as well.
Thank you, I'm new.**

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `LastWriteTime` property to your `pscustomobject` and the `Select-Object`

```
$dir = "\\server\BackupBuddy" 
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Directory |
ForEach-Object{
[pscustomobject]@{
    Folder = $_.Name
    Count = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -File).Count
    LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
    }
 } | Select-Object Folder,LastWriteTime,Count
```